# jQuery Displaying Info Based On Dropdown Information

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Right now, I have a code that lets me show prices based on which membership option is selected. It looks like this:

```
<p>Current Status: 
    <select id="status" name="status" onchange=YourFunction()> 
        <option value="">Please Select</option> 
        <option value="A">Associate</option>
        <option value="F">Family</option> 
        <option value="R">Regular</option>
        <option value="RF">Regular Family</option> 
        <option value="H">Honary</option> 
        <option value="I">Institutional</option>
    </select>
</p>
<script type="text/javascript">
function YourFunction(){
    if($('#status').val()=="A"){
        $("#price").html("35");
    }
    else if($('#status').val()=="F"){
        $("#price").html("40");
    }
    else if($('#status').val()=="R"){
        $("#price").html("35");
    }
    else if($('#status').val()=="RF"){
        $("#price").html("40");
    }
    else if($('#status').val()=="H"){
        $("#price").html("0");
    }
    else if($('#status').val()=="I"){
        $("#price").html("25");
    }
    else if($('#status').val()==""){
        $("#price").html("0");
    }
}
</script>

<div id="price">0</div> $ Membership Dues
```

I need a script that will take the value that is generated by this script and put it into this input box:

```
<input type='text' name='paid' onblur="getTotal()"/></p>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
$('input[name=paid]').val($("#price").html());
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/WS2dn/1/)

Comment: It kind of works, but I need it to update when the dropdown changes. would I do that with a function?

Comment: Just put it in `YourFunction()` function. See the FIDDLE

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#status').change(function() {
  myUpdate();
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/vfp6K/1/